# Joomla Hacked and redirecting to dndelectric website

Tags: joomla

I have searched in all my files for what could be re-directing or putting this malware into my sites to no avail. Anyone who has had this before? Its spread across multiple sites I have hosted. The common component with them is jevents but even the codes for that have not been changed.

Is there a way I can block these requests from .htaccess?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You really need to take your site offline - actually remove the files from the server and identify what type of hack this is.

First though I would suggest turning off javascript in your browser and visiting your page - do you still get redirected?

If not - then the problem is either:

a) a javascript file has been added to your site - or an existing javascript file has been edited. Examine all the .js files loading in the page.

b) an sql injection has added javascript directly into your articles (perhaps each and every article

Assuming you ARE redirected while is javascript turned off - then you are looking at either:
a) an edited .htaccess file redirecting you elsewhere
b) an edited (or 'included') php file setting headers and taking you elsewhere.

Are any of the add-ons in your site(s) listed here:
http://www.exploit-db.com/search/?action=search&filter_page=1&filter_description=joomla&filter_exploit_text=&filter_author=&filter_platform=0&filter_type=0&filter_lang_id=0&filter_port=&filter_osvdb=&filter_cve=

You need to know whether it is only your site compromised or whether it is other sites on the server, or even whether the server itself has been taken over, and that is a question for your host.  Immediate re-infection after rebuilding from a backups could mean:
a) a cron job has been set up to re-infect you at a set period
b) another account on the server is infected and is reaching out to re-infect others
c) your site was compromised previously (dropped files within the site) but that these are sat dormant waiting for either an individual or a botnet to connect and take control.
d) or that the server is totally compromised and the hacker just reconnects to re-infect

There are some steps you could take - but frankly this is one area where if you need to ask it is probably a sign you aren't equipped to deal with the issue without expert assistance.

1. You could grep your files for likely file patterns c99, r57, web shell, eval(base64decode(, etc.
2. You could scan for    files with recent creation dates or recent modified dates/times

Files changed in the last x days (1 days in this case)

```
find . -mtime -1
```

Files changed between two dates

```
find . -type f -newermt "2010-01-01" ! -newermt "2010-06-01"
```

1. You should scan log files for suspicious activity
2. You could download the files and let your anti-virus program scan them - this can give you a    place to start (don't let it delete the files though as their    contents can give further clues).
3. You should block access from known automated / scripted useragents (wget, libwww, etc)

All in all though you could spend days battling this with no guarantee of success. My advice would be to get some assistance from a Joomla security expert.

Comment: I have identified what is happening but still have no clue as to how its happening. My .htaccess file keeps getting changed. And by .htaccess I mean one is being created on the root folder for my websites. Not in the individual folders. I have deleted and created a new one, changed permissions to 644 but the new one still gets created. How do I go about this?

Comment: Is there a linux command to check file modified by? The re-direction url also changes with time. It is not constant so it means there is a script changing the .htaccess.

Comment: I've seen this before (and fixed it), there is a script executing somewhere on your server that is pushing the malicious code into your .htaccess file.  Usually that script is included somewhere, inserted into a php file and it typically calls to some code that executes and inserts the redirection stuff into your .htaccess - best bet is chasing down the script that's executing.  Get Firebug, use NoScript and start hitting it!

Comment: I can see the php files, problem is that I cannot see what and how they are being created. Even if I delete them, they get re-created after a day or two.

Comment: The find command works for me. You can add more grep -v "some-strings-to-filter" to exclude some folders from the search.

Comment: You even can make a cronjob for it to detect if there is any changes for your files and notify you over email when some files changed for every 5 minutes for example.

Answer (score 2):

For your next installation, you might want to consider installing also host-based intrusion detection system [OSSEC](http://www.ossec.net/). It offers several security features, including **File Integrity checking** which would have detected the tampering of your .htaccess files. OSSEC is free and open-source.

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably have to really compare directories and if you can, the original installations of the extensions you used.  Check directory permissions - if you see something with 777 or unusually high permissions then that could be a good start to where the problem may be originating from.  Check error logs too that may point to something missing or something that has changed and is now throwing an error.

You want to try and identify the problem/malware/virus because it will help you with the next part.

Find the last backup before you were hacked that is a good valid copy, and go from there.  Best bet is to completely get rid of the current site and restore from backup (fully) - assuming the backup doesn't contain the virus/malware.

Sometimes there will just be one or two lines of code added to existing lines of code that cause the redirect - these are tough to trace down and identify, but you can do it if you compare sizes and such.  Just time consuming.  I hope this information helps - good luck.

Also, it sounds like your whole server is compromised if it's spreading - do not use the same password for multiple sites, or the default username (admin).  Always change the passwords and the username.  If you leave the username default as 'admin', hackers already have 50% of the login figured out.  Make it tough on them by changing the user name.  Alert your host you've been hacked - they will help in these cases, and can keep it from spreading any further than your account.  Change your passwords with that host, change the passwords for each site (preferably after you've cleaned the malware/virus).

Comment: It seems to be changing as its now fetching some other files. So so weird!! Guess I will have to re-do most of the sites from ground up.

Comment: You won't need to as long as you have valid backups.

Comment: If you don't take backups - then you should.  Akeeba Backup is free, and is pretty much the best backup solution for Joomla sites available.  Literally one-click backups that take care of your database and your entire site.  It's absolutely essential to have that on any Joomla site, just for instances like this.  Make sure and let your host know too - a lot of times they're very helpful in these cases.  Good luck!

Comment: I use akeeba backup. I have a few. The funny thing is that when I restore from a backup, it also gets 'nuked'. Problem might be with my host 'Dreamhost' Have sinced notified them.

Comment: Yea, talk to Dreamhost let them know what's going on.  You may want to check your backups too - could be that you're restoring from an already infected backup (sounds like it could be the culprit), FTP in and take a look around - find anything crazy?  Get rid of it.  Check all folder permissions and change passwords.

Comment: Resurrecting with Akeeba puts the site back as it was before but it may be that you were hacked months ago, but only just exploited. Alternatively, the hack could be exploiting a vulnerability within your site (within old Joomla, or extension, etc). This would be trivial to re-exploit.  It could be a cronjob, it could be someone elses account being exploited, it could be that a dropped script has compiled and installed a new binary) it *could* be almost anything. Leaving an exploited or easily exploitable site live on the web for this long is bad for everyone. Take it down and get expert help.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this same .htaccess hack on my shared hosting account.  I had 5 sites running Joomla! v 1.5 <---> 2.x.  After hours of experimenting with permissions and every other conceivable way to thwart the malicious .htaccess files from regenerating, I found that two of my live Joomla! installs had mysterious .php files in the 'tmp' directory [joomla_root/tmp].  One file was named something like 'jos_AjnJA.php' and the other file was 'j.php'. I changed the permissions on those two files to 000, then once again restored my original .htaccess files to their respective folders. Presto! The .htaccess files finally did not get maliciously rewritten within minutes, as before. 24 hours later and everything is still working as it should on all my Joomla! installs.

I cannot stress enough: I am sure there are variations of this exploit, but do yourself a huge favor and first check all tmp folders on your Joomla! installs for any suspicious .php files!